# Problem with softwares and PPAs in Softwares & Updates in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

Many of the softwares that was installed in ubuntu 18.04 cannot be opened in 18.10 after upgradation. some of them are "google play music", "Riseup-VPN" atom editor. How to open them? Also some PPAs in software and updates tools are showing disabled on upgrade to cosmic. How to enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Atom

Run these commands to quickly and easily install and upgrade the Atom text editor snap package from the terminal in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (64-bit only).

- Install Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo apt install snapd  
  sudo snap install --classic atom
  ```

  Note that a snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Atom extension packages are installed into the user's home directory.
- Upgrade Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo snap refresh --classic atom
  ```

Atom text editor can also be installed from the Ubuntu Software application in Ubuntu 18.10. Either way there is no need to add a PPA to your software sources.

Atom is more than just another text editor. Atom is extensible through the installation of Atom packages that can give Atom the capabilities of running code, showing inline graphical output and more.

[image]

### Google Play Music

1. Visit https://dl.bintray.com/marshallofsound/deb/pool/main/G/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player/
2. Download google-play-music-desktop-player_4.0.3_amd64.deb.
3. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the google-play-music-desktop-player_4.0.3_amd64.deb file that you downloaded.
4. Install Google Play Music.

   ```
    sudo apt install ./google-play-music-desktop-player_4.0.3_amd64.deb
   ```

### Find which PPAs to remove after upgrading

1. Open *Software & Updates* by searching it from the Dash.
2. Click the *Other Software* tab.
3. Find any lines relating to the repositories which are giving you problems.
4. You can remove a software source in Software & Updates by selecting the software source which you want to remove, and clicking the *Remove* button.
5. After clicking the *Remove* button in the *Other software* tab in Software & Updates a new small **Authentication Required** window opens up that looks like this. Type your user password and click the *Authenticate* button.

   [image]
6. A new small window opens up with a **Reload** button that refreshes the list of available software. The Reload button is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot.

   [image]

   ```
   The information about available software is out-of-date 

   To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources,  
   you have to reload the information about available software.

   You need a working internet connection to continue.
   ```

   Clicking the **Reload** button in Software & Updates does the same thing as running `sudo apt update` in the terminal.